# NodeJS and JS Timestamps Differ by 45 Seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, timestamp

I'm using NodeJS as my server-side language, and am using `new Date().getTime()` to generate a new millisecond timestamp.  I'm then using a client-side JS function to calculate the time ago, which also uses `new Date().getTime()` to generate a timestamp with which to compare the server timestamp to.  However, on new items the time ago is inaccurate, and calling `new Date().getTime()` in my client console and my node console at the same time results in timestamps differing by ~45 seconds.  I'm using AWS for my server hosting, if that could affect it in any way.  Why could this be happening?  I know it isn't code-related since even the consoles differ from one another.

Comment: Computer clocks are not all magically in sync with each other.

Comment: a 45 second discrepancy is a little much

Comment: I suggest to check your server NTP configuration

Comment: Why would you expect the clocks to be closer together? Are you running an NTP service?

Comment: Why not have the server send the delta instead?

Comment: @BertrandMartel generally you don't run NTP from something like an AWS instance - the host systems do that and the VM clocks sync to that.

Comment: @Pointy is the difference constant enough where I can just apply a delta?

Comment: Probably not. Computer clocks are really quite inaccurate, which is why people use network-based time synchronization. If you're dealing with web-based clients, you can't predict *anything* about the accuracy of their clocks.

Comment: Then how do services like facebook accurately serve their time deltas

Comment: They probably just look at server-side timestamps. Also, who cares whether Facebook is off by a minute or two about when a post was made? You don't have to care about client clock accuracy if you don't want to. It depends on the application. But it's just a fact that client clocks are not reliable and *might* be arbitrarily wrong.

Comment: I found out that I was right in that 45 seconds is far too much to be naturally off.  I compared my timestamp with another system, a phone and the epoch website, and in all accounts they are all exactly 43 seconds off from the server timestamp.  Then, after running `date +%s` in the AWS instance, it showed the the instance time was indeed off by 43 seconds.  Trying to fix that now, will update

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the issue did in fact lie within my AWS instance.  My system also had the incorrect timestamp, which I discovered using the command `date +%s`.  Virtual machines tend to have a lot of problems with maintaining the correct system time, and AWS runs its non-dedicated systems (and possibly its dedicated ones, too) on virtual machines.  I resynced my time with the command `sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org`.  It can be, however, dangerous in production to create such an instant jump in time, so I found a [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-12-04) that shows how to set up NTP to slowly readjust your system clock when it is out of sync.  This solved all timestamp issues I was having!

Answer (score 0):

Use single source of truth, don't check client-side time, as it executes on browser of user(who can live in China with 6 hours difference)

For server, use time as it is, no magic. But for client-side, make ajax request to server to get server-time, so that all clients over the world and your server are synced correctly, obviously http-request needs some time, average 50ms, but it's worth it. Even if your server time is incorrect, all clients will be synced to your server-time